# Find all strings in between two strings multiple times

Tags: java, regex, string

I understand this may be a duplicate but I have not found an answer that satisfies this question. I have a large string that is set up like so:

season
content content content content content
season
content content content content content
    season
content content content content content

etc.

I want to get all of the content in between the "season" string and put that content in to a List. This is my code so far but it does not work, it does not match anything...

```
String pattern = "season";
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(pattern+"(.*?)"+pattern);
    Matcher m = pattern2.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

When I use StringUtils.substringBetween() it does work but I need to get every string in between two "season" strings.

Comment: Are those new lines?

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to use a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) to assert either `season` or the end of the string follows. As well if newline sequences are between the pattern you want to use the dotall flag making the dot `.` match newlines also.

```
String s  = "season\nfoobar foobaz\n\nseason\nbarbaz\nseason\nbazquz";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)season\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*season|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    arrayList.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(arrayList); // [foobar foobaz, barbaz, bazquz]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Season {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String largeString = "season content content content content content season content content content content content season content content content content content";
        List<ArrayList<String>> lists = getStringBetweenSeason(largeString);
        for (ArrayList<String> list : lists) {
            for (String str : list)
                System.out.println(list);
        }

    }

    public static List<ArrayList<String>> getStringBetweenSeason(
            String largeString) {
        if (largeString == null)
            return null;
        List<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for (String str : largeString.split("season")) {
            if (!str.trim().isEmpty()) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String strContent : str.split(" ")) {
                    list.add(strContent);
                }
                lists.add(list);
            }
        }
        return lists;
    }
}
```

----- If pattern matching is the target -  then this seem to work too..

```
public static ArrayList<String> getStringBetweenSeason(String largeString) {
        if (largeString == null)
            return null;
        ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("season" + "*.*" + "season");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(largeString);

        while (m.find()) {
            lists.add(m.group());
        }

        return lists;
    }
```

Comment: `season*.*season` Matches `seaso some text note the incomplete first wordseason`...